# New page for every user

Tags: javascript, firebase

What i basically want to do is to log in a user and make a new page for every user with its own personal details. 
So for example user A signs in, he would have a different view than user B. 
I am using javascript ans firebase for back end. 
How can i make that happen?
A rough idea would be enough.

Comment: For a start, it's not like you create a new page for every user. You use the exact same page, but fill it out using different data. We call that templating.

Comment: Make a rough template with the things you want every user to see, then add the specific stuff according to the settings you saved for each user. After they log in, fetch the settings you need for that specific suer and update the page accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Sessions for each user and one the bases of Session value you must populate values for the user each user will have seperate details and each user will have different data page will be same but data will be different so user feels that he has a new page